# When will a road reach a certain condition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, regression

I have an exponential regression equation that is designed to predict the future condition of a road at a certain age:

`condition = 21-EXP(0.06*age)`

*Note: Road condition is a range from 1 to 20; a road with a condition of 20 is in perfect condition.*

---

**Question:**

I know that a road has a condition of 9.4.

How many years will it take for the road to reach a condition of 8? Can this be gleaned from the original equation?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? This seems like a problem-set question you are asking us to solve. The current age is implicitly defined by $9.4=21-\exp{0.06*current~age}$. The age for 8 is implicitly defined by $8=21-\exp{0.06*age~for~8}$. The answer to your question is difference between the two ages.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1: Call the equation $$C = 21 - e^{0.06A}$$ How would you solve this in terms of A?

Hint #2: When would the road be in the worst condition?  How many years would this take?